# Specific length of substring between two specific characters

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling to find a way to do this via SQL (postgres).

I want to create a condition which looks for a pattern inbetween "@" and "." on an email, but only when it contains exactly 5 letters. Say for instance for email address 'user@domain.com', as the word domain is in the right place and contains exactly 5 letters I'd like to see that email address in my results. The letters can be any casing but can only be letters with no numbers, hyphens etc.

I have used this in the past to focus on anything past the "@" but have been unsuccessful in instructing it to only look for 5 letters only before the "."

```
SUBSTRING(email,(POSITION('@' IN email) + 1),252)
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a regular expression:

```
select *
from your_table
where email ~ '@[^.]{5}\.[^.]*'
```

The regex means: `@` followed by 5 characters that are not a `.` followed by a `.` then followed by any number of characters

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually haven't got the capacity to test it as I switched companies before I could give it a go. Can you please advise, should I clikc the tick to close question or leave open for someone else to verify it works? Thanks and sorry again for not being able to verify this myself.

Comment: Thank you, syntax does look correct but I can't run it myself as I have no access to a postgres database anymore. It does answer my question though so will mark it as closed. Thanks again for all your help.